# Why does while loop OR not work but AND does?

Tags: c#, while-loop, conditional-statements

I have a simple while loop in C# and basically I'm testing two conditions

```
while (opponentOne.HP >= 0 || opponentTwo.HP >= 0)
```

Which when I read this means, while the first opponents HP is more than equal to 0 OR the seconds opponents HP is more than equal to 0, exit. So when only one of them are true, exit the while loop?

However this does not do what I want it to do, it waits for both of them to become true before exiting the loop, however if I change || to && it will work

```
while (opponentOne.HP >= 0 && opponentTwo.HP >= 0)
```

Which now says while the firsts opponents HP is more than 0 and the seconds opponent is more than 0, exit...

Have I got something mixed up here?

I thought the loop should break when both conditions are met.

Comment: It's "while the first opponents HP is more than equal to 0 OR the seconds opponents HP is more than equal to 0, *continue*."

Comment: It's not really an incorrect/correct issue, this is what is happening, either though I say OR it waits for both, not just one

Comment: Thanks, I understand what I was doing wrong now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition isn't the condition "to exit", it's the condition to continue
So first one says "continue looping as long as either oponents have >0HP" and the second one says "continue as long as both opponents have >0HP"

Answer (score 0):

> Have I got something mixed up here?

Yes,  `&&` means that both sides must be `true`(both oppponents must be alive), otherwise the loop is exited.

`||` means that one of both sides must be true, so only one opponent must be alive.

Replace the `while`-loop with an `if`-statement(for demonstration purposes only):

```
if(opponentOne.lives && opponentTwo.lives)
{
   // do something
}
else // one is dead
{
   // exit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A while loop will keep looping until the condition BECOMES FALSE.

So in the first case :

NOT (1.HP >= 0 || 2.HP >= 0)

if we apply DeMorgan's equivalency to it:

It will break when

NOT 1.HP >= 0 AND NOT 2.HP >= 0